# What exactly does ./configure --enable-shared do during python altinstall?

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I altinstall python 2.7.12 with

> ./configure --prefix=/opt/python --enable-shared

it comes up as python 2.7.5 (system default python)

But without

> --enable-shared

it comes up as 2.7.12, what am I missing?

This is on RHEL 7.2

---

This is not a pathing issue:

Without --enable-shared

> [root@myrig ~]# /opt/python/bin/python2.7 -V
>
> Python 2.7.12

With --enable-shared

> [root@myrig ~]# /opt/python/bin/python2.7 -V
>
> Python 2.7.5

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Compiling python like this fixed my issue:

```
./configure --enable-shared --prefix=/opt/python LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath=/opt/python/lib
```

Courtesy Ned Deily:

The problem is, that on most Unix systems (with the notable exception of Mac OS X), the path to shared libraries is not an absolute path.  So, if you install Python in a non-standard location, which is the right thing to do so as not to interfere with a system Python of the same version, you will need to configure in the path to the shared library or supply it via an environment variable at run time, like LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  You may be better off avoiding --enable-shared; it's easy to run into problems like this with it.

Ref: https://bugs.python.org/issue27685

Comment: Do you mean that the reason why you got different python versions was the differences in working directories , not the existence of  `--enable-shared`, between the two builds?

Comment: @bombs: No, the reason for having different python versions is the executable `/opt/python/bin/python2.7` was linking to the system python library (version 2.7.5), not the one that was just built (version 2.7.12). Adding `-rpath` to the build adds a library search directory for that executable, which makes it find the correct shared library.

Comment: worked for me, because of that i was not able to install wsgi module also properly thanks..

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure why the version number is different, but Graham Dumpleton says at [this](https://github.com/docker-library/python/issues/21) website that "When running configure, you should be supplying the --enable-shared option to ensure that shared libraries are built for Python. By not doing this you are preventing any application which wants to use Python as an embedded environment from working."

Answer (score 5):

With ldd comand you can view where the executable is searching for libraries:

```
ldd python2.7
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffa75ec000)
    libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007f717042e000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f7170211000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f716fe46000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f716fc2c000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f716fa28000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f716f824000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f716f51b000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055969d00b000)enter code here
```

You can change the lib search path of python2.7 setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable in the environment (non-persistent):

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/python/lib
```

or setting a persistant system-wide way:

```
echo "/opt/python/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/python.conf
ldconfig -v
```

or setting a persistent executable way:

```
patchelf --set-rpath /opt/python/lib/ python2.7
```