# Why do I get `undefined symbol: _Py_RefTotal` when debugging a program using a custom-built Python installation? (with Bazel)

Tags: python-2.7, gdb, clion, bazel

I have built Python2.7  with `--enable-shared` and ensured that the RPATHs are correctly setup.

If I run the binary using `bazel run -c dbg --run_under="gdbserver localhost:9999"` and connect to it with CLion, it works, but then I do not find all of the source files I want.

I can run the binary with `Run...` under CLion, configuring it as `bazel run`.

However, if I run the binary with `Debug...` (still using `bazel run`) under CLion, I get the following error:

```
undefined symbol: _Py_RefTotal
```

How do I fix this?
I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, with system-distributed GDB (7.11.1). I built Python with the following flags (using https://stackoverflow.com/a/48175708/7829525 as a guide):

```
./configure --with-pydebug CFLAGS='-O0 -g' --enable-shared \
    --prefix=~/.local/python/2.7.12-dbg \
    LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath=~/.local/python/2.7.12-dbg/lib \
    --with-ensurepip=upgrade
make -j install
```

Answer (score 1):

Found that the issue was that the Bazel CLion plugin by default does *not* incorporate the parent's environment when debugging.

Here's the repro project I used for the following pics:
https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/tree/b900846766fd1d4f8a8cdad268298767a917cacc/bug/clion_python_debug_shared

To fix this, you should ensure that incorporate your parent's environment into the debug executable:
[image]
[image]

This was done with CLion 2017.2.3, Bazel Plugin 2018.01.02.0.1, Bazel 0.10.1.

Note that if you're using GDB Python extensions (http://droettboom.com/blog/2015/11/20/gdb-python-extensions/), you may want to rebuild GDB with this version of Python:

```
git clone git://sourceware.org/git/binutils-gdb.git
git checkout gdb-7.11.1-release 
./configure LIBS='-lpython2.7' LDFLAGS="-L~/.local/python/2.7.12-dbg/lib" --prefix ~/.local/python/2.7.12-dbg --with-python
make -j VERBOSE=1
make -C gdb install
```